# expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)

Tags: c++, set

I don't know what I did wrong that causes this error to appear.

This is the wrong code in the program:

```
if (set<int>::iterator itr = s.find(x)) {
```

And here is the whole program:

```
int main() {
    set<int>s;
    int q, y, x;
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        cin >> y;
        if (y == 1) {
            cin >> x;
            s.insert(x);
        }
        else if (y == 2) {
            cin >> x;
            if (set<int>::iterator itr = s.find(x)) {
                s.erase(x);
           }
            else {
            }
        }
        else {
            cin >> x;
            if (set<int>::iterator itr = s.find(x)) {
                cout << "Yes";
            }
            else {
                cout << "No";
            }
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this error?

Comment: what do you expect `if (itr)` to do?

Comment: `if (set<int>::iterator itr = s.find(x); itr != s.end()) {`

Comment: Probly too late, but I think you wanted a comma rather than a semicolon @Eljay

Comment: I use if (itr) because I want to find if element "x"  is in the set or not.

Comment: You need to compare it against `end()` iterator to check if element is in container or not: `if( (set<int>::iterator itr = s.find(x)) != s.end() )`. I strongly recommend setting the variable outside of `if` to reduce syntax complexity.

Comment: @user4581301 the semicolon is correct. `if(<init>; <condition>)` is new syntax introduced in C++17, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: Sneaky buggers.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I closed the question as duplicate, no answers for me I guess